# Downloading genes from NCBI in fasta format

Tags: fasta, phylogenetics, data-download, sequence

I'm pretty new in bioinformatics.

I need to download FASTA sequences of several genes. The list of genes I have assembled consists of 140 genes, so I'd rather do this through via code than download each gene manually from the NCBI database.

The genes belong to 2 different organisms (bacteria) I have chosen, most of them are found in both organisms and some are specific to one or the other bacterium.

I've tried running this code which I found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/

```
esearch -db nucleotide -query "aminoacyl-tRNA\ hydrolase" | efetch -format fasta
```

The gene of interest being aminoacyl-tRNA hydrolase here. But I don't know how to filter it for the specific organism, Neisseria meningitidis. Tried running this, without luck:

```
esearch -db nucleotide -query "aminoacyl-tRNA\ hydrolase" | efilter -organism [Neisseria meningitidis] | efetch -format fasta
```

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Hi how does the list of 140 gene you are interested in look like? do you have gene accessions, or Ids or just gene symbols?, ie symbol: BRCA1 ; id : 
    672 ; accsession NC_000017.11 , are all the same gene.

Comment: what output do you get from your commands? nothing, an error, the wrong gene?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and add a few lines of your input file. Presumably, you have a list of genes, so please show us the list so we can understand the input format.

Comment: @user12256545 Right now I have the list on a word-document with locus name and gene-ID (that would be "pth" and 61281026 for aminoacyl-tRNA hydrolase). All genes seem to have the same accession nr. so that won't be useful unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

If I put the species name in quotes, I get expected (by me) output:

```
% esearch -db nucleotide -query "aminoacyl-tRNA\ hydrolase" | efilter -organism "Neisseria meningitidis" | efetch -format fasta
# outputs:
>NZ_JWNU01000010.1 Neisseria meningitidis strain Nm440716 Scaffold10, whole genome shotgun sequence
GACCGCCTATTCGCTTGCCGCCGGCGGCCCCATCATGCAGGCAGGATTACACGCCTTCACACTCGTACCC
# [snip, tons of output]
```

Note that filtering down to only *N. meningitidis* still leaves all of the different sequenced accessions of this species, such that you will still have a lot of different annotated copies of this gene. You will need to filter more specifically to reduce that.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you! What would you suggest I use as identifier to filter more specifically? I tried substituting "aminoacyl-tRNA\ hydrolase" with gene-ID (61281026) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Vjon I would suggest trying an [NCBI taxid](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/TaxIdentifier/tax_identifier.cgi) in place of the species name.